# Reclassify land use map based on agricultural statistics

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, spatial-statistics, reclassify, land-cover

I'd like to create a land cover map of Greece with enhanced information on the spatial distribution of agricultural crops.

As you know, common land cover products (such as ESA CCI LandCover or CORINE) only account for "arable land" without specifying crops cultivated on it. My intention now is to consult agricultural crop statistics of Greek regions in order to create a land cover map including crops. I'd like to distribute the crops over the arable land of each region so that the proportional distribution within each region matches the statistics.

As this is only a statistic approach, the exact location of the different crops remain uncertain, of course. So some kind of random generator distributing a number of, let's say, wheat pixels within a region would be suitable.

Do you have any idea how that could be done using ArcGIS? I have examined the numerous (Re-)Classify and Statistical Analysis tools in ArcGIS, but none of them seem to be suitable. Further I thought about creating a random raster, but there is no way to define custom value proportions, rather some distribution types (normal, gamma, etc.).

Comment: I was typing an answer when it got closed!

Comment: Just thinking out aloud here, I'm sure someone will offer a slicker approach?  1. Extract out cells that are only agricultural.  2. Convert this raster into points.  3. Randomly select the number of points as a proportion of the area of wheat for the agricultural area and tag as wheat. 4 Repeat for other crop types. 5. Convert your tagged point layer back into a raster and mosaic with original land cover map.